# How to store and retrieve meta-information in generator function object instance?

Tags: python

Is there a way which I can return more information to the caller that instantiate the generator function than just the function instance itself?

For example,

```
def genFn(a, b, c):
    # some initialisation / pre-computation
    startPt = fn(a, b, c)
    data = (yield None)
    while True:
        # perform some computation
        data = (yield result)

f = genFn(5, 6, 7)
start = f.get("startPt") # this line syntax is wrong - just to show what I want
f.send(None)
for data in dataseries[startPt:]:
    k = f.send(data)
    ...
```

Based on the passed-in parameter (a, b, c), the function has the logic to compute the earliest data it requires. I like to somehow be able to return this information "the earliest data it requires" back to the caller. Although I can certainly get the caller to compute and arrive at the same information - it is a duplication of effort and it isn't elegant because I want to encapsulate the complexity in the generator function.

Thanks

T

Comment: Why not return it when you send `None`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return it as the currently unused return value of first `send` call.

```
def genFn(a, b, c):
    # some initialisation / pre-computation
    startPt = fn(a, b, c)
    data = (yield startPt)
    while True:
        # perform some computation
        data = (yield result)

f = genFn(5, 6, 7)
startPt = f.send(None)  # first yield returns the start point
for data in dataseries[startPt:]:
    k = f.send(data)
```

By the way, `.send(None)` is same as `.next()`.

Or you could use a class and use generator as one of its methods. The pre-computation would be done in `__init__` and data could be accessed through instance attributes.

```
class GenCl(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.startPt = fn(a, b, c)

    def gen(self):
        startPt = self.startPt  # get the startPt calculated in __init__
        data = (yield None)
        while True:
            # perform some computation
            data = (yield result)

o = genCl(5, 6, 7)
startPt = o.startPt
f = o.gen()  # create the generator object
f.send(None)
for data in dataseries[startPt:]:
    k = f.send(data)
```

Yet another idea is to use closures. Function call would return the generator and the start point, for example in a tuple.

```
def genFn(a, b, c):
    # some initialisation / pre-computation
    startPt = fn(a, b, c)
    def gen():  # actual generator function
        data = (yield None)
        while True:
            # perform some computation
            data = (yield result)
    return gen(), startPt  # returns generator and startPt

f, startPt = genFn(5, 6, 7)
f.send(None)
for data in dataseries[startPt:]:
    k = f.send(data)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think your method 1 is what I need. It is surprisingly simple - I didn't know we can use the first send(None) to return result. The other 2 methods though are more OOP but it requires more code and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a special class that can be sent to the generator to get it to return your special value.

```
class GetStartPt:
    pass

def genFn(a, b, c):
    startPt = fn(a, b, c)
    data = (yield None)
    while True:
        if data is GetStartPt:
            data = (yield startPt)
            continue
        # compute here
        data = (yield result)

f = genFn(5, 6, 7)
f.send(GetStartPt)
```

However, you might be better off writing a wrapper class for this:

```
class GenClass(object):
     def __init__(self, a, b, c):
         self.startPt = fn(a, b, c)
         def generator(startPt, a, b c):
             data = (yield None)
                 while True:
                 # compute here
             data = (yield result)
         self._generator = generator(self.startPt, a, b, c)
     def __iter__(self):
         return self._generator
     def next(self):
         return self._generator.next()
     def send(self, value):
         return self.generator.send(value)
```